# Error while installing Koha

Tags: mysql, perl, perl-module

I get this error when installing via the web installer, the error says:

```
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1 at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Objects.pm line 101
```

Installed version is: 16.05.05.000

I installed using packages by following the instructions on this link: https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_Debian

The database I'm using is: MySQL database; and it is on the same machine as Koha.

Any idea please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Koha Integrated Library System in ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792085/installing-koha-integrated-library-system-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: The original is not solved either @Chankey

Comment: If you do not receive answer for this question also then will you keep on asking same question again and again?

Answer (score 1):

I was presented with the same error. It appears that the error is given in an enum column in the database. For MySQL you can solve it as follows (inside the MySQL database administrator):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

When setting the mode with an empty string `''` you are telling MySQL not to take into account some errors that arise when inserting data.

MySQL can operate in different modes, some modes are more restrictive than others, for example, some modes do not allow certain operations, such as division by zero or restrict the way in which the dates are represented in the database.

To see how the server is, you must log into MySQL from the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If the MySQL server does not have a password (which is not recommended), omit the -p parameter. You can then check the mode with the following command

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

It will return more or less similar to this:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

You can find more information on this at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

[Source](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30862/error-al-importar-las-plantillas-marc-21-en-koha-dbixclassstoragedbi-d)

Comment: I had to start again all over. And now I get stack here:    ERROR: Module mpm_itk does not exist! How to overcome @Sohail

Answer (score 0):

1. install phpmyadmin on different port (say 81)
2. select koha_library database (where *library* is the instance)
3. select ‘search_filed’ table
4. press ‘structure’ tap
5. select 'type' column and then press 'change'
6. change the type to varchar and length to 255  (**or you can change the type of column 'type'in table ‘search_filed’ from enum to varchar(255) using the terminal**)
7. execute the following command in server terminal (login using `mysql-u root -p` ):

   ```
   SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';
   quit;
   ```
8. `sudo service mysql restart && sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Or [just use](http://schema.koha-community.org/17_05/tables/search_field.html) `ALTER TABLE search_field MODIFY type varchar(255);`